# NodeRed - reports insufficient space at startup

Tags: raspberry-pi3, node-red

I tested ModbusTCP communication and after a few hours NodeRed stopped working for me. How to solve this error? There is enough space on the SD card.

[image: screenshot putty when Node-Red start]

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of text, they are very hard to read and impossible for people that need to use screen readers. Please post the actual text and use the toolbar to format it

Comment: How have you checked that there is space? What does running `df -h` show?

Comment: Yes, it reports a full card, but I have a newly installed rasbian + nodered. How do I find out what takes up space on my card?                                                                 


`Filesystem = /dev/root     Size = 15G  Used = 15G Avail =0% Use =100%`

Comment: That is a question for [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/),[Unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com). But you probably want to be looking at using the `du` utility probably with the `--max-depth=1 -h` options